# Scrapy:Rename downloaded file name to a string with unicode cause messy characters

Tags: python, unicode, scrapy, python-2.x

I'm trying to scrap some PDF from a website using, instead of letting Scrapy name these files I want to name these PDF with the titles I scraped from the website.So I define `ReportsPDFPipeline` and override the `file_path` function.

```
class ReportsPDFPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response = None, info = None):
        #print("我被调用了")
        file_guid = request.meta["title"]
        return "full/%s" % (file_guid)
```

The problem is that there are some unicode(Chinese) characters in the `title`, so no PDF files were stored in this path.

Then I tried a simple case:

```
class ReportsPDFPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response = None, info = None):
        #print("我被调用了")
        return u"full/" + u"我被调用了" + u".PDF"
```

This time, the file could be renamed and stored but there are some messy characters like this:

[image]

What am I supposed to do to rename the files correctly?

Comment: I suspect that your default filesystem encoding isn't UTF-8. What does `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` return? BTW, Unicode handling is a lot saner in Python 3.

Comment: @PM2Ring I just ran `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` on my virtual server and  my local environment, both of them return `utf-8`

Comment: Oh well, it was worth trying. What OS are you using?

Comment: @PM2Ring it's Ubuntu 16.04 x64

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce that messy filename. `s = u"full/" + u"我被调用了" + u".PDF"; a = s.encode('utf8'); print(a.decode('latin1'))` prints `full/æè¢«è°ç¨äº.PDF` in my UTF-8 terminal. Sorry, I'm not sure how to fix this. I guess you could try passing the UTF-encoded filename instead of the Unicode.

Comment: I just tried creating a file in Python 2 on Linux using `s = u"full_" + u"我被调用了" + u".PDF"` `with open(s.encode('utf8'), 'w') as f:` `f.write('test\n')`, and it behaved correctly.

Comment: I tried `s = u"full_" + u"我被调用了" + u".PDF"` and then `return s.encode("utf8")`, but it still output the same result. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I guess Scrapy is doing something strange to the filename. I don't know Scrapy, so I don't know what to suggest to get around that. Maybe the Python 3 version works correctly...